# Query based on individual COUNT(*) values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, count

I have two tables ('posts' and 'votes') which allows users to vote thumbs-up (where rating = 1 in 'votes') or thumbs-down (where rating = 0 in 'votes') on posts.

I'm joining the two tables in a query and am trying to filter the results so that a row only shows if it has 2+ positive (rating = 1) ratings AND 2+ negative (rating = 0) ratings from the 'votes' table ('post_id' and 'rating' columns).

This is what I got, but it doesn't work as intended, since it brings back results which also have only 1 positive and 1 negative vote -- although you can't see this due to the conglomeration of votes for each post -- which isn't what I want (the 'HAVING' line isn't working as intended):

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*)
FROM posts p
JOIN votes v ON p.id = v.post_id
WHERE rating = 1 OR rating = 0
GROUP BY p.id 
HAVING COUNT(rating = 1) > 1 AND COUNT(rating = 0) > 1

+----+---------+----------+----------+
| id | post_id | rating   | COUNT(*) |
+----+---------+----------+----------+
|  4 |       4 |        0 |        2 |
|  7 |       7 |        0 |        2 |
|  9 |       9 |        0 |        2 |
| 83 |      83 |        1 |        2 |
+----+---------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this `having` clause:

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(*)
FROM posts p JOIN
     votes v
     ON p.id = v.post_id
WHERE rating IN (1, 0)
GROUP BY p.id 
HAVING ABS(SUM(rating = 1) - SUM(rating = 0)) > 1;
```

EDIT:

The above is doing the right thing.  [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4712b/1) is a SQL Fiddle showing the results.

EDIT II:

I might have misinterpreted the question.  I understood the question to be a *net* positive of two votes or a *net* negative of two votes.  You seem to want just at least two votes either way.  That `having` clause is:

```
HAVING SUM(rating = 1) > 1 or SUM(rating = 0) > 1
```

Comment: This brings back 0 results, even though one post has 2 positive and 2 negative votes

Comment: @user1228907 . . . The expression that you want is `SUM(rating = XXX)`, not `COUNT(rating = XXX)`.  `COUNT()` counts non-NULL values, so the two would return the same value, regardless of whether `XXX` is `0` or `1`.

Comment: That seems strange.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I changed the 'OR' to 'AND' since it's the combination of the two votes as you now know.